# adding second columns with duplicate elements in first column

Tags: java, arrays, sum

I have a 2 dimensional array with 6 rows and 2 columns and I want to sum the value in the 2nd column based on the value in the 1st column. I don't know what to do next to transfer the values I saved into the sortedArray.

Basicaly I want to change this :

```
      { 1, 5},
      { 1, 10 },
      { 2, 5},
      { 2, 15},
      { 2, 10},
      { 3, 6},
```

into this:

```
      { 1, 15},
      { 2, 30},
      { 3, 6},
```

Here is my code so far, so any help would be appreciated.

```
  int [][] sortedArray = new int[3][2];
  int [][] array = {
      { 1, 5},
      { 1, 10 },
      { 2, 5},
      { 2, 15},
      { 2, 10},
      { 3, 6},
      };
  int column1 = 0;
  int column2 = 0;

  for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
  {
     array[i][0] = column1;
     while(array[i][0] == column1)
     {
        column2 += array[i][1];
     }
  }
```

Comment: You should edit your question to state what your code, as it it does in contrast to what you want.

Comment: and what are you getting with your current code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do it in generic way in case you don't know the number of unique values in first column.

```
    // Build a map with
    final Map<Integer, Integer> sortedMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    for (int[] ints : array) {
        if (sortedMap.containsKey(ints[0])) {
            sortedMap.put(ints[0], sortedMap.get(ints[0]) + ints[1]);
        } else {
            sortedMap.put(ints[0], ints[1]);
        }
    }
    int[][] sortedArray = new int[sortedMap.size()][2];
    int i = 0;
    // Convert the map to 2D array
    for (Integer integer : sortedMap.keySet()) {
        sortedArray[i][0] = integer;
        sortedArray[i][1] = sortedMap.get(integer);
        i++;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
for (int i=0; i<array.length; i++) // Iterate over each item in your array
{
    // Process each item in your array into your sorted array.
    for (int j=0; j<sortedArray.length; j++)
    {
        if (sortedArray[j][0] == array[i][0]) {
            // If the value has already been seen, sum with existing.
            sortedArray[j][1] += array[j][1];
        } else {
            // If the value has not yet been seen, insert.
            sortedArray[j][0] = array[i][0];
            sortedArray[j][1] = array[i][1];
        }
    }
}
```

This assumes that the values in the first column of `array` are always increasing (as per your example). It also assumes there's sufficient space in `sortedArray`, ie. it's created with as many rows as there are distinct values in the first column of `array`.